# How to remove screen msgs after grub2 menu?

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, fsck, bpfilter

After grub2 stage, I get a black screen with the below texts appearing. Next, Ubuntu 18.04 boots up successfully.

```
[    0.940493] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
/dev/nvme0n1p3: clean, 300714/1525920 files, 3457087/6103552 blocks
Started bpfilter
[    2.453984] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[    2.568940] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[    2.570752] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[    2.604204] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
```

**Questions:**

1. Can I avoid their appearance? If so, how? I noticed that in grub2,
   `ro quiet splash $vt_handoff` has already been set.
2. I have ran `e2fsck -p /dev/nvme0n1p3` and `e2fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p3`
   after a Ubuntu 18.04 USB startup disk boot. Even after these
   commands completes successfully, the msg `/dev/nvme0n1p3: clean, 300714/1525920 files, 3457087/6103552 blocks` still persist. How do
   I fix this issue?
3. How can I switch off the appearance of the line `Started bpfilter`?
   I found some write-ups on bpfilter here [1](http://vger.kernel.org/netconf2018_files/DanielBorkmann_netconf2018.pdf), [2](https://linux-audit.com/bpfilter-next-generation-linux-firewall/) and [3](https://www.netronome.com/blog/bpf-ebpf-xdp-and-bpfilter-what-are-these-things-and-what-do-they-mean-enterprise/). It seems to be built into [linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/bpfilter/main.c#L59) w/o a off switch?

Thank you.

**Updates:**

*W.r.t. Q1:* I came across this [webpage](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/silent_boot) and added to grub `quiet loglevel=3`,  and `quiet loglevel=3 rd.systemd.show_status=auto rd.udev.log_priority=3`, respectively. Both these command only suppressed the appearance of `[    0.940493] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e` but not the rest msgs shown above. I got the same result even with `quiet loglevel=0`.

*W.r.t. Q2:*
I tried the approach mentioned [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2336775&p=13543085#post13543085):

1. Find where are the superblock backups via terminal cmd: `$ sudo mke2fs -n /dev/nvme0n1p3`
2. Try every superblock backup until a working one is found via terminal cmd: `$ sudo e2fsck -y -b {block number} /dev/nvme0n1p3`. For every try, I rebooted the system to check if backup superblock worked.
3. However, non of the backup superblocks worked. :(

I found out the msgs `PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key` were caused by `Using NVidia driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-430(proprietary, tested)`. When I used `Using X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver from xserver-org-video-nouveau(open source)`, those msgs did not appear.

**Good news???** According to **reply #5** in this [Ubuntu discussion](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/293967), the msg `/dev/nvme0n1p3: clean, 300714/1525920 files, 3457087/6103552 blocks` simply confirms that the filesystem in `/dev/nvme0n1p3` is clean( i.e. the filesystem is ok, no fix needed.) **The reason this msg appeared is because of timing differences between the GPU and graphics drivers, i.e. one could be quicker or slower with their initialization.**  Quoting **Manfred Hampl:**

> This can lead to the fact that on some computers such informational
>   message might be shown longer, before the Ubuntu welcome screen is
>   hiding that message, and on other computers there might just be a
>   short display before graphical display uses the full screen.

Based on the above, I am suspecting these linux boot msgs that I am seeing is an artifact of timing differences between the `NVidia driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-430(proprietary, tested)` and the NVidia GPU used.

To investigate this possibility, I explored purging nvidia drivers and reinstalling them again. Previously, I was using the nvidia drivers provided by the [Graphics Drivers team](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). Recently, I learnt that Ubuntu will provide NVIDIA driver updates via Stable Release Updates through its repositories, starting with Ubuntu 18.04, hence no more need for PPA type graphics drivers. This was what I did:

1. Press Ctrl + Alt + F3 for access tty3 and login.
2. `sudo apt update`
3. `sudo apt upgrade`
4. `sudo apt remove nvidia-*`
5. `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
6. `sudo apt update`
7. `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
8. `ubuntu-drivers list`
9. `sudo reboot`

However, this procedure did not remove the appearance of any of the above mentioned msgs.

The system that I am working on a nvme and a HDD storage medium, and each holds a unique installation of Ubuntu 18.04. I noticed the above msgs appears only when Ubuntu 18.04 from the nvme is boot up. When the Ubuntu 18.04 from the HDD was booted up, the msg shown appeared only:

```
/dev/sdb3: clean, xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx files, xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx blocks
```

This Ubuntu system was the newest install, although the same Ubuntu installation disk and version were used. The msg `PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key` can be seen on both systems during `$ dmesg -l err`. Yet it seemed that it only appeared during bootup with the 1st Ubuntu 18.04 install made on the nvme disk. How strange??? On the same hardware system (except one is in a nvme disk and the other is in a HDD disk) and same Ubuntu version, I can get different linux boot msgs.

I found out that the grub file in `sdb3/etc/default/grub` was used to create the grub menu(the newest installed Ubuntu 18.04 system). I wanted to see what would happen if I was able to return to use the `nvmen0p3/etc/default/grub` file in the earlier installed Ubuntu 18.04  system to bootup Ubuntu. I used "boot repair" to effect the change. The procedure mentioned in [If Manjaro is not involved](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273083/169155) were used.

After rebooting, I noticed that when I selected booting with Ubuntu 18.04 in the nvme disk, this msg appeared:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p3: clean, 300714/1525920 files, 3457087/6103552 blocks
Started bpfilter
```

whereas when I selected booting with Ubuntu 18.04 in the sdb3 disk, this msg appeared:

```
[    x.xxxxxx] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
/dev/sdb3: clean, xxxxx/xxxxxxx files, xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx blocks
[    x.xxxxxx] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[    x.xxxxxx] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[    x.xxxxxx] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[    x.xxxxxx] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
```

How strange...

**Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e**

[1](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2380700) & [2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1743908) are Ubuntu discussion threads on the cause of this msg.

Comment: I see similar messages and sometimes even a terminal login prompt on my systems that use Nvidia graphics.  They do not seem to cause any problems.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Comparing the outcome from using Nouveau and Nvidia drivers, I concluded that the msgs `PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key` were caused by the use of nvidia drivers. They appeared on both of my Ubuntu 18.04 distro when I issued the cli cmd `dmesg -l err`. Yet, it only appeared in the boot screen when Ubuntu 18.04 in the nvme disk was selected and not when Ubuntu 18.04 in the sdb3 was selected. Recently I tried using the Nvidia driver provided via Ubuntu Stable Release. That did not fixed the issue.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I also tried using Boot Repair to revert to booting grub using the grub file from the first Ubuntu 18.04 install. On the boot screen, the msgs `PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key` did not appear but it did appear in the kernel boot log seen when dmesg -l err was issued. Interesting too is that the msgs `PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key` now appears in the boot screen after the grub menu when Ubuntu 18.04 in the sdb3 disk was selected.  Is my issue related to grub?